# Using processing sound library

Tags: audio, processing, libraries

I would like to use processing sound library:

```
import processing.sound.*;
```

But I have the following error:

```
No library found for processing.sound
Libraries must be installed in a folder named 'libraries' inside the 'sketchbook' folder.
```

How can I install the sound library? I tried to add it via *Sketch* > *Import library...* but I can't find it.

I'm using Processing 2.2.1 on MacOS 10.9.5

Any idea?

Comment: What version are you using and on what OS? Because there were troubles with sound libraries on Win. Anyway you can build it by yourself from [git](https://github.com/processing/processing-sound)

Comment: @Majlik I just added the version information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use **minim**, which is a very popular sound library for `processing`. 
You can find and use the libary here: http://code.compartmental.net/tools/minim/
If you are using Processing you should already have Minim. 
Go to *Sketch -> Import Library -> minim*

If you still don't find it, Try *Go to Sketch -> Import Library -> Add Library -> Minim*

You can import the library like this:

```
import ddf.minim.*;
```

Answer (score 5):

This library is available for Processing 3.0+.

To install it, type exactly `processing.sound` in library installer. Then you'll find it.